# What are some great passages from Caesar?

Tags: gaius-iulius-caesar, passage-request, bellum-gallicum, bellum-civile

I'm interested in reading some passages from Julius Caesar, so that I can practice my Latin and get a better sense of classical prose. I don't have time to read the entire *Bellum Gallicum* or *Bellum Civile* in Latin, but I would like to read some of the more interesting parts.

I'm looking for passages up to 15 lines in length from either of his memoirs. What do you think are some especially moving, insightful, or historically important passages that fit this criteria? If you could give the book and the line numbers, along with a short description, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opening of BG I is a good place to begin. BG V.12 has his description of the inhabitants and V.13 the geography of Britain. BG VII.6 is news of the Gallic uprising and Caesar's decision to return.

The beginning of B.Civ is worth reading for some strong writing.

Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: That's definitely helpful. Thanks. I would be interested in any other feedback as well.

Comment: Agreed that you should start with the beginning of *BG* if you haven't read it already: *Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres* is a rite of passage for Latin learners :)

Comment: Another section that might interest you is B.Civ Vi, the short chapter where Caesar crosses the Adriatic in pursuit of Pompey. It contains a sentence which some have seen as the origin of the saying "between a rock and a hard place".